# Frustum culling works correctly but results in flickering meshes

Tags: unity, c#, compute-shader, frustum-culling

I've written a C# code and Compute Shader that makes frustum culling and it works correctly but it makes the grass flicker. I can't figure out what is behind this issue so I'm asking here. Does anybody know what's wrong with it?

C# Script:

```
private Camera camera;

struct DrawData
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public Quaternion rotation;
    public Vector3 scale;
}

[HideInInspector]
public Mesh mesh;
[HideInInspector]
public List<Matrix4x4> matrices;
[HideInInspector]
public Material material;

[Range(0, 1000f)] 
public float distanceCutoff;

private List<DrawData> instances;

private ComputeShader cullShader;
private ComputeBuffer drawDataBuffer, argsBuffer, voteBuffer, scanBuffer, groupSumArrayBuffer, scannedGroupSumBuffer, resultBuffer;

private int numThreadGroups, numGroupScanThreadGroups;

private uint[] args = new uint[5];
private MaterialPropertyBlock mpb;

private void Awake()
{
    camera = Camera.main;
    mpb = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
    
    instances = new List<DrawData>();
    LoadInstances();

    drawDataBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(instances.Count, Marshal.SizeOf<DrawData>());
    drawDataBuffer.SetData(instances);
    
    numThreadGroups = Mathf.CeilToInt(instances.Count / 128.0f);
    numGroupScanThreadGroups = Mathf.CeilToInt(instances.Count / 1024.0f);

    cullShader = Resources.Load<ComputeShader>("ComputeShaders/Cull");

    voteBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(instances.Count, 4);
    scanBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(instances.Count, 4);
    groupSumArrayBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(instances.Count, 4);
    scannedGroupSumBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(instances.Count, 4);
    resultBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(instances.Count, Marshal.SizeOf<DrawData>());
    
    argsBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(5, sizeof(uint), ComputeBufferType.IndirectArguments);
    args[0] = mesh.GetIndexCount(0);
    args[1] = (uint)instances.Count;
    args[2] = (uint)mesh.GetIndexStart(0);
    args[3] = (uint)mesh.GetBaseVertex(0);

    mpb.SetBuffer("_DrawData", resultBuffer);
}

private void CullGrass(Matrix4x4 VP)
{

    argsBuffer.SetData(args);       

    // Vote
    cullShader.SetMatrix("MATRIX_VP", VP);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(0, "drawDataBuffer", drawDataBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(0, "voteBuffer", voteBuffer);
    cullShader.SetVector("cameraPosition", camera.transform.position);
    cullShader.SetFloat("_distance", distanceCutoff);
    cullShader.Dispatch(0, numThreadGroups, 1, 1);
    
    // Scan Instances
    cullShader.SetBuffer(1, "voteBuffer", voteBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(1, "scanBuffer", scanBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(1, "groupSumArray", groupSumArrayBuffer);
    cullShader.Dispatch(1, numThreadGroups, 1, 1);
    
    // Scan Groups
    cullShader.SetInt("numOfGroups", numThreadGroups);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(2, "groupSumArrayIn", groupSumArrayBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(2, "groupSumArrayOut", scannedGroupSumBuffer);
    cullShader.Dispatch(2, numGroupScanThreadGroups, 1, 1);
    
    // Compact
    cullShader.SetBuffer(3, "drawDataBuffer", drawDataBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(3, "voteBuffer", voteBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(3, "scanBuffer", scanBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(3, "argsBuffer", argsBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(3, "resultBuffer", resultBuffer);
    cullShader.SetBuffer(3, "groupSumArray", scannedGroupSumBuffer);
    cullShader.Dispatch(3, numThreadGroups, 1, 1);
}

private void Update()
{
    Matrix4x4 P = camera.projectionMatrix;
    Matrix4x4 V = camera.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
    Matrix4x4 VP = P * V; 
    
    CullGrass(VP);
    
    Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedIndirect(mesh, 0, material, new Bounds(Vector3.zero, Vector3.one * 100.0f), argsBuffer, 0, mpb);
}

private void LoadInstances()
{
    instances.Clear();
    foreach (var matrix in matrices)
    {
        instances.Add(new DrawData()
        {
            position = GetPositionFromMatrix(matrix),
            rotation = GetRotationFromMatrix(matrix),
            scale = GetScaleFromMatrix(matrix)
        });
    }

    Debug.Log($"Initialized {instances.Count} instances of grass.");
}

private Vector3 GetPositionFromMatrix(Matrix4x4 matrix)
{
    return matrix.GetColumn(3);
}

private Vector3 GetScaleFromMatrix(Matrix4x4 matrix)
{
    return new Vector3(matrix.GetColumn(0).magnitude, matrix.GetColumn(1).magnitude, matrix.GetColumn(2).magnitude);
}

private Quaternion GetRotationFromMatrix(Matrix4x4 matrix)
{
    float w = Mathf.Sqrt(1 + matrix.m00 + matrix.m11 + matrix.m22) / 2f;
    float x = (matrix.m21 - matrix.m12) / (w * 4);
    float y = (matrix.m02 - matrix.m20) / (w * 4);
    float z = (matrix.m10 - matrix.m01) / (w * 4);

    return new Quaternion(x, y, z, w);
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    argsBuffer?.Release();
    drawDataBuffer?.Release();
    voteBuffer?.Release();
    scanBuffer?.Release();
    groupSumArrayBuffer?.Release();
    scannedGroupSumBuffer?.Release();
    resultBuffer?.Release();
}
```

Compute shader:

```
#pragma kernel Vote
#pragma kernel Scan
#pragma kernel ScanGroupSums
#pragma kernel Compact
#pragma kernel ResetArgs

#define NUM_THREAD_GROUPS_X 64

struct DrawData
{
    float3 position;
    float4 rotation;
    float3 scale;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<uint> argsBuffer;
RWStructuredBuffer<DrawData> drawDataBuffer;
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> voteBuffer;
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> scanBuffer;
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> groupSumArray;
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> groupSumArrayIn;
RWStructuredBuffer<uint> groupSumArrayOut;
RWStructuredBuffer<DrawData> resultBuffer;

float4x4 MATRIX_VP;
int numOfGroups;
groupshared uint temp[2 * NUM_THREAD_GROUPS_X];
groupshared uint grouptemp[2 * 1024];
float _distance;
float3 cameraPosition;

[numthreads(128, 1, 1)]
void Vote(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float4 position = float4(drawDataBuffer[id.x].position, 1.0f);

    float4 viewspace = mul(MATRIX_VP, position);

    float3 clipspace = viewspace.xyz;

    clipspace /= -viewspace.w;

    clipspace.x = clipspace.x / 2.0f + 0.5f;
    clipspace.y = clipspace.y / 2.0f + 0.5f;
    clipspace.z = -viewspace.w;

    bool inView = clipspace.x < -0.2f || clipspace.x > 1.2f || clipspace.z <= -0.1f ? 0 : 1;
    bool withinDistance = distance(cameraPosition, position.xyz) < _distance;

    voteBuffer[id.x] = inView * withinDistance;
}

[numthreads(NUM_THREAD_GROUPS_X, 1, 1)]
void Scan(uint3 id : SV_DISPATCHTHREADID, uint groupIndex : SV_GROUPINDEX, uint3 _groupID : SV_GROUPID,
          uint3 groupThreadID : SV_GROUPTHREADID)
{
    int tid = (int)id.x;
    int groupTID = (int)groupThreadID.x;
    int groupID = (int)_groupID.x;

    int offset = 1;
    temp[2 * groupTID] = voteBuffer[2 * tid];
    temp[2 * groupTID + 1] = voteBuffer[2 * tid + 1];
    int d;
    int numElements = 2 * NUM_THREAD_GROUPS_X;

    for (d = numElements >> 1; d > 0; d >>= 1)
    {
        GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();

        if (groupTID < d)
        {
            int ai = offset * (2 * groupTID + 1) - 1;
            int bi = offset * (2 * groupTID + 2) - 1;
            temp[bi] += temp[ai];
        }

        offset *= 2;
    }

    if (groupTID == 0)
    {
        groupSumArray[_groupID.x] = temp[numElements - 1];
        temp[numElements - 1] = 0;
    }

    for (d = 1; d < numElements; d *= 2)
    {
        offset >>= 1;

        GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
        if (groupTID < d)
        {
            int ai = offset * (2 * groupTID + 1) - 1;
            int bi = offset * (2 * groupTID + 2) - 1;
            int t = temp[ai];
            temp[ai] = temp[bi];
            temp[bi] += t;
        }
    }

    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();

    scanBuffer[2 * tid] = temp[2 * groupTID];
    scanBuffer[2 * tid + 1] = temp[2 * groupTID + 1];
}

[numthreads(1024, 1, 1)]
void ScanGroupSums(uint3 id : SV_DISPATCHTHREADID, uint groupIndex : SV_GROUPINDEX, uint3 _groupID : SV_GROUPID,
                   uint3 groupThreadID : SV_GROUPTHREADID)
{
    int tid = (int)id.x;
    int groupTID = (int)groupThreadID.x;
    int groupID = (int)_groupID.x;

    int offset = 1;
    grouptemp[2 * groupTID] = groupSumArrayIn[2 * tid];
    grouptemp[2 * groupTID + 1] = groupSumArrayIn[2 * tid + 1];
    int d;

    for (d = numOfGroups >> 1; d > 0; d >>= 1)
    {
        GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();

        if (groupTID < d)
        {
            int ai = offset * (2 * groupTID + 1) - 1;
            int bi = offset * (2 * groupTID + 2) - 1;
            grouptemp[bi] += grouptemp[ai];
        }

        offset *= 2;
    }

    if (tid == 0)
        grouptemp[numOfGroups - 1] = 0;

    for (d = 1; d < numOfGroups; d *= 2)
    {
        offset >>= 1;

        GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();
        if (tid < d)
        {
            int ai = offset * (2 * groupTID + 1) - 1;
            int bi = offset * (2 * groupTID + 2) - 1;
            int t = grouptemp[ai];
            grouptemp[ai] = grouptemp[bi];
            grouptemp[bi] += t;
        }
    }

    GroupMemoryBarrierWithGroupSync();

    groupSumArrayOut[2 * tid] = grouptemp[2 * tid];
    groupSumArrayOut[2 * tid + 1] = grouptemp[2 * tid + 1];
}

[numthreads(128, 1, 1)]
void Compact(uint3 id : SV_DISPATCHTHREADID, uint groupIndex : SV_GROUPINDEX, uint3 _groupID : SV_GROUPID,
             uint3 groupThreadID : SV_GROUPTHREADID)
{
    uint tid = id.x;
    uint groupID = _groupID.x;
    uint groupSum = groupID.x > 0 ? groupSumArray[groupID.x] : 0;
    bool inCamera = voteBuffer[id.x];

    if (inCamera == 1)
    {
        InterlockedAdd(argsBuffer[1], 1);
        resultBuffer[scanBuffer[tid] + groupSum] = drawDataBuffer[tid];
    }
}

[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void ResetArgs(uint3 id : SV_DISPATCHTHREADID)
{
    argsBuffer[1] = (uint)0;
}
```

Video: https://youtu.be/K53G4NpnYxY

Comment: This looks like it could be an edit to [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/210177/39518), since it's about the same topic of "how do I correctly implement frustum culling for instanced meshes when using a Unity compute shader"

Comment: It's not an edit, it's a new question because a guy in comments said I should be asking differently, so I'm asking differently. If you can see, I've made quite a progress to a frustum culling and it now works but wrongly. :)